# How fast can clocks go?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, time, observers

We know that clocks can move slower when near a massive object, however, how FAST can clocks go? Can clocks go as fast as they want?

Comment: First of all, it's not the clocks that move slower. It's the measured time. What do you exactly mean with "how fast can they go"?

Comment: 1 second per second

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that there are two measures of time: proper time and coordinate time.

Proper time is the physical time measured by a clock. All valid clocks measure proper time at a rate of 1 second of proper time per second of proper time (obviously). So proper time does not slow down.

Coordinate time is simply a convention that is chosen for a given coordinate system. It is non-physical and almost completely arbitrary. When we talk about clocks slowing down what we mean is that there is more than one second of coordinate time per second of proper time. Because coordinates are largely arbitrary, that ratio can be made arbitrarily large or small, simply by choosing appropriate coordinates.

For example, in a Schwarzschild black hole spacetime, we can choose the reference clock at some finite distance outside the horizon instead of “at infinity”. Then other clocks will go faster. By choosing a reference clock arbitrarily close to the horizon we can make any other clock go arbitrarily fast.

Answer (score 0):

First off: it is awkward to phrase this kind of question in terms of 'how fast/slow clocks are running'. It's not about the clocks, it about how much *time* elapses, and it is worthwhile to let the wording reflect the physics.

If you have two spacecrafts, one orbiting close to a massive object, the other orbiting at a large distance to that massive object, then the amount of proper time that elapses for the two of them will be different.

Let's say that the lower orbiting spacecraft completes 100 orbits for every single complete orbit of the higher orbiting spacecraft.

They compare clock readings every time the higher orbiting spacecraft has completed an orbit. (There will be transmission delay, but that delay will be the same every time, so it drops out.) Then it will be seen that for the lower orbiting spacecraft a smaller amount of proper time is elapsing than for the higher orbiting spacecraft. That difference is cumulative.

Third spacecraft:
You can put another spacecraft in orbit, orbiting even further away, but there is only so much difference you can achieve. Gravitational effect is proportional to the inverse of the square of the radial distance

$$ \frac{1}{r^2} $$

As you try higher and higher orbits: pretty soon the gravitational effect is so small that the difference with zero gravitational effect is negligable.

So:
If you are coming from a region of space with negligable gravitational effect: yeah, you can make a *big difference* by moving into low orbit around a massive object.

But there is nothing you can do in the other direction. If you already are in a region of space where you are subject to negligable gravitational effect then you are already *maxed out*, as far as time is concerned. There is nowhere you can go to  such that for you more proper time is elapsing than for other spacecrafts not-subject-to-gravitational-effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you lived next to a black hole, and you looked at a clock out in distant space, you'd say "wow, is that clock ever running fast!"   But here on Earth time dilation is really really small.  The time dilation factor compared to theoretical free space is about 1.000,000,000,699    This theoretical free space is where time runs fastest.  It can't run any faster than that.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest one is in CMB reference frame. Our galaxy moving 600 km/s with respect to CMB reference frame. Basically CMB reference frame has the average velocity all moving galaxies.